# iOS collectionView: how to scroll a cell to the top of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am wondering if there is a way to scroll a certain `UICollectionViewCell` to the top of the view? 
I tried the `collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath()` method, but instead of scrolling the cell to the top of the view, it scroll the cell to the center of the view.

Comment: Is there are more cell, below the `indexpath`'s cell you are scrolling?

Comment: Can you put up the actual code? I mean with the parameters.

Comment: Do you want to scroll to top of collection view or move a specific cell to top of collection view with animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use below code:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

However, if you want to force the scrolling, then try this.

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(cell.center.x - collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.5, cell.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement the UIScrollViewDelegate method scrollViewShouldScrollToTop: and return YES if the passed in scroll view is equal to the one that you want to scroll to the top:

```
-(BOOL) scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView*) scrollView 
{
    if (scrollView == self.myTableView)
       {
          return YES;
       }
    else 
       {
          return NO;
       }
}
```

if  you don't have more than one scroll view/table view/collection view on screen